# Intel NIC not found on ProLiant CentOS 7 install

Tags: linux, networking, network-adapter, centos-7, hp-proliant

I am trying to install a CentOS 7 distribution on an HPE ProLiant DL360 Gen10 server. Installed is an Intel X520 2P 10GB NIC in a PCIe slot.

On the CentOS Installation screen, in the Network & Hostname menu the following behaviour occurs:

1.) With a DAC connected on boot to port 1 of the Intel NIC: The interface is not listed at all, only the second port of the Intel NIC is shown. 4 other interfaces of the embedded NIC are displayed alongside.

2.) With nothing connected on boot: Both interfaces of the Intel NIC are displayed. Once a DAC is connected, the "Unplugged" text next to that interface disappears, but the logo is still showing an unplugged cable. Once I config that interface with the correct IP/DNS details, and switch it on using the toggle switch in the top right, nothing happens. No network details pull through. The toggle switch also defaults back to the "off" position once you click off that interface.

Some things:

- I have tried different DACs
- I have updated the server's firmware
- I have tried the second port of the NIC, same behaviour.
- There are network lights on the NIC once connected.
- The NIC worked doing the same install but in a PowerEdge (clue?)
- I have also fiddled with some of the network settings in the BIOS, no luck.

Has anyone had anything similar or have a hunch as what to try next?